# How does coastal fog form on the Chilean coast?

Tags: meteorology, climate, clouds

When traveling through the northern parts of Chile (La Serena, Antofagasta) during November and December, I noticed a thin layer of coastal fog very close to the coastline.

Since this fog was present for several weeks, I assume it to be not a short-term weather phenomenon - but why does it arise then?
Is it the same phenomenon as in San Francisco, for example (i. e. cold(er) Humboldt Current meets hot continental air → air cools down → fog)?